# What are the pros and cons of introducing new safety colors for hunting?

Tags: safety, hunting

As indicated in [Have there been any studies done on how fluorescent pink compares to fluorescent orange?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19602/have-there-been-any-studies-done-on-how-fluorescent-pink-compares-to-fluorescent), fluorescent pink is becoming accepted as a new safety color for hunting. Given that we have a color that already works, are there advantages that outweigh the disadvantages of either that would drive this addition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From everything I have read, its **mostly about giving hunters who would prefer wearing pink to orange the choice to do so**.

> Before taking a hunter safety class in October 2016, sisters Paige and Brooke Simonsen, from Easton, stocked up on pink hunting clothes. **Then, they found out that Maryland law did not allow hunters to wear any color besides blaze orange.**
>
> “Our instructor mentioned that other states **have pink and we only have orange, and we wanted to change that so we went to Senator (Addie) Eckardt,**” Paige, 12, said.
>
> The legislation, which passed in both chambers Monday night, adds “daylight fluorescent pink” as an alternative color for hunters. The legislation is based in part on the Simonsen family’s research.

[Source](https://wtop.com/maryland/2018/04/maryland-hunters-can-now-wear-pink-thanks-to-two-sisters/)

in Wyoming,

> Sen. Affie Ellis, who sponsored the bill adding pink, said her motive for adding the color was not about providing a way for some hunters to look fashionable or “sexy” but **simply to give hunters a choice that is safe during the hunting season.**

[Source](http://trib.com/news/state-and-regional/govt-and-politics/wyoming-to-allow-hunters-to-wear-fluorescent-pink-attire/article_45ab81d5-6e15-548a-b394-d589e726d138.html)

It's worth pointing out that the **point of wearing blaze orange/ pink isn't to signify that you are a hunter, but that you are not an wild animal**( if you have horses/mules they need to be wearing something as well) and even if you are not hunting its still a really good idea to wear blaze orange in the woods during hunting season.

On the con side, people might not realize right away that pink is as legal as orange, but they aren't going to mistake it for a deer for example.

[If pink works](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19602/have-there-been-any-studies-done-on-how-fluorescent-pink-compares-to-fluorescent) as well as orange, and some hunters would prefer pink, I don't see a reason not to allow them to do so.